# Showing multiple tables with partial views. Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views

I want to use 3 partial views to display my search result(Client name) in 3 different tables. I do not want to show any info from the tables before the search has been completed. As i have understood you can only use one model per view, unless you make some workarounds.

I have tried to make a view model so i can reference the multiple tables from both the index and the partial views. But can't figure it out. Since the methods for the 3 different tables will be the pretty much same i am only going to post the code for the client table. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
    {

        public List<Clients> allClients { get; set; }
        public List<OrderLines> allOrders { get; set; }
        public List<ViewNewOrderSum> allViewNewOrderSum { get; set; }

    }
```

HomeController:

```
using testForAutofill.Models;

public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        test_Db_Context db = new test_Db_Context();
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
            vm.allClients = GetClients();
            return View();
        }

     private List<Clients> GetClients()
        {
            List<Clients> clientList = new List<Clients>();
            clientList = db.Clients.ToList();
            return clientList;
        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm)
        {

            Scaleit_Db_Context db = new Scaleit_Db_Context();
            List<Clients> orderSums;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))//Fix this!
            {
                orderSums = db.Clients.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                orderSums = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(searchTerm)).ToList();
            }
            return View(orderSums);
        }
```

IndexView:

```
@using testForAutofill.Models;
@model testForAutofill.Models.ViewModel

@if (Model.allClients != null && Model.allClients.Count() > 0)
{
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <b>Kundenavn:</b>
    @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
    <input type="submit" value=" Search" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-search" />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3 card-client" style="max-width: 40rem;">
            <div class="card-header">Kunde</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    @foreach (Clients clients in Model.allClients)
                     {
                      @Html.Partial("_Client", clients)
                     }
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

_Client:

```
@model testForAutofill.Models.ViewModel

//Tried both DisplayFor and not.
    <tr>
        <th>Kunde:</th>
        <td>@Html.Model.allClients.Name</td>// This is where the error gets 
                                            // thrown.
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Org.nr:</th>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => clients.OrgNr)</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Adresse:</th>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => clients.Address1)</td>
        @if (clients.Address2 != null)
        {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => clients.PostNr)</td>
        }
    </tr>
```

The program/webpage doesnt run, and i get the error message:

> " CS1061: 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
>   'Model' and no extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)".

At the commented line in the Partial view.

Comment: Try "@Model.allClients.Name" instead of "@Html.Model.allClients.Name"

Comment: This gives me a red line under Name with: "Cannot convert method group 'Name' to non-delegate type 'Object' Did you intend to invoke the method?"

Comment: Yes, because allClients is a list and does not have Name on it. When you are rendering the partial ```@Html.Partial("_Client", clients)``` you are passing a "Clients" object to the partial. If that is you're intention then the _Clients partial should have the model ```@model testForAutofill.Models.Clients``` (maybe a better name is Client). And then it will have @Model.Name on it.
Is that you're intention?

Comment: Then you also need to change ```<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => clients.Name)</td>``` to ```<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</td>``` for all the ```@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ...```

Comment: Now it runs, but it shows all the clients before i search. The table with clients is gonna be way to big for that to be useful.

Comment: My intention was that i must search by Client name and then post the search result data to the corresponding partial views. I have 3 different tables and 3 different partial views. When i only use one model in the index view everything works as it should. Nothing is showing before i press search.

Comment: So you're View should the have a input and a button for search. You're controller needs to have a parameter to receive the query. ```public ActionResult Index(string query = "")```. If you there is no query then set ```vm.allClients = new List<Clients>();``` so that its empty. If there is a query then filter the allClients list based on that query. There is a guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-2.2 .. only difference for you should be the  new List<Clients>() if query is empty.

Comment: @Paul Adam I updated the code here to include my search method and input/submit field. I'll check this out. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

TRY:
Set object on viewData

inside controller:

```
    ActionResult SomeView(){

     ViewData["object"] = theObj;
     return View();

    }
```

inside cshtml:

```
@using objectNamespace

@(((objectType)ViewData["object"]).name)
```